# Hibernate Criteria and NULLs

Tags: java, hibernate

Im building a Hibernate Criteria that will fetch all Appartments with a valid contract-date.
There is a One-To-One relationship between an Appartment and a Contract. They are not embedded.
A contract is not mandatory, so an Appartment may not have a contract.
A contract has a start and end-date, but they are not mandatory so one or both may be NULL.

- If there is no contract, it means the Appartment has a never ending contract.
- If the contract start is NULL, it means the contract has lasted from the dawn of days
- If the contract end is NULL, the contract is valid forever.

Basicly i'm sending an integer to my DAO. The integer indicates the year. The DAO should return all Appartments that was/is valid sometime during that year.
That means it should return:

- All Appartments without a contract
- All appartments with a startDate before or equal to this year, and NULL as endDate
- All Appartments with a endDate equal to or after this year, and NULL as startDate
- All Appartments with startDate equal or before this year and enddate equal or after this year.

So far i am unsure on how to handle the NULLs. And also how to compare the year to a date-field. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

I have gotten this far:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Appartment.class)
    .setFetchMode("contract", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .createAlias("contract", "c")
    .add(Restrictions.le("c.startDate", ????))
    .add(Restrictions.ge("c.endDate", ????));
```

Comment: Well never mind the NULLs. I've refactored my code to do default values and not make them nullable. I'll the year comparison as a separete question and closing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the null, you need to use the explicit [`NullExpression`](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/NullExpression.html) criterion, just like you would have used if you wrote direct SQL.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more detailed info on how exactly to use it? Im googling it right now, but cant find any decent examples..

Comment: What's there to it? [`Restrictions.isNull(propName)`](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#isNull(java.lang.String)) I didn't try it out (I would have to set up the whole stack), but I'd be surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, but it does not really adress my problem. I need to set a default value on the null-values. Eg. if startdate is null then treat it as 01-01-1980. I'd like to do it all in one statement.

Comment: There's `coalesce` for that in Hibernate. I can check out the Criterion API to see if it's there. I checked, there's no first-class support. They direct you to use the general facility `sqlRestriction`.